# how can you deploy smart contracts on main ethereum network?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created a dapp and using truffle I have migrated and tested it on ganache, I was wondering how can I deploy same application on main ethereum network.

Comment: its really easy developing smart contracts using parity. they give you a contract interface afterwards where you can see all variables and execute functions easily. you should try that

Answer (score 0):

to deplay the smart contract: instead of deploying it to the Ropsten Test Network, deploy it to the Main Ethereum network (Homestead/Mainnet) using Metamask